# Current options for installing an R for data science stack on Windows

Tags: r, windows, installation, data-science, rstudio-server

I'm a college professor who teaches a data science course for behavioral science graduate students.  The course uses Git, GNU Make, R (>=4.0), RStudio, and Pandoc + LaTeX.  I do all of my work on Mac, and the students who use Windows regularly hit major walls getting these Unix-based tools installed.  What are some current (November 2021) options for installing this stack of tools on Windows, and the pros and cons of each approach?  (Note that I'm not asking which is the "best," but instead a relatively objective presentation of pros and cons that I can use to develop a recommendation.)

Comment: Git Bash, R Tools 40, miktek should do. You can use `installr` within R to install most of these. The question is likely to be opinion based though.

Comment: I know a lot of instructors are using RStudio server for teaching (i'm not sure if that can come with other tools like GNU make). Another option: you could create a custom AWS image with everything installed, save it, and let your students work from it. That would mean they have to have a stable internet connection because they'd be remoting into a VM. Another option: you could also consider docker. Just a bunch of ideas, I'm keen to learn more about this too.

Comment: Microsoft provides the winget package manager.  Type  winget at the Windows cmd line to see if you have it already.  There is also the [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) package manager for Windows.

Comment: Since I don't have access to Windows, it would be helpful if some of these comments were expanded into answers that discussed cons as well as pros.  For example, based on the docs I can't tell whether installr includes make, and I don't have a way to check whether Windows package managers have R 4.0 or later.

Comment: The chocolatey site has a list of all packages that it has.  Suggest you find someone with Windows to try out both package managers for you.  Alternately you can use bootcamp on your Mac to run Windows yourself if you have an Intel based Mac.  By the way, another option is that Windows users can run WSL which is a Linux subsystem provided by Microsoft.  It is free but you have to install it.  Probably not optimal though for naive users who don't know Linux.